# Can I trigger a command after ffmpeg writes a segment?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am reading from an RTSP (camera) stream and writing segments, using ffmpeg. My command to do so is:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://$camera_creds@$camera_ip/video/1 -map 0 -c:v h264 -preset:v ultrafast -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment -segment_time 300 -strftime 1 
-segment_list ${monitor_dir}/segments$camera.txt $monitor_dir/cam${camera}_out%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.mp4
```

It works fine to a point. My problem is that I want to do something with each segment once it has been written.

To accomplish this, I monitor the segmentsN.txt file for lines being added to it; I then read the contents, do stuff (process, upload), and then remove the lines that I've already processed (so that I don't reprocess them).

The problem with this is that periodically, ffmpeg will start writing to a new segment, but apparently won't update the segments list file. Initially I thought this was because my "remove the lines" operation was writing a brand new file and replacing it in place (which it was), while ffmpeg was probably continuing to append to the inode it started out with (which it maybe was). Having fixed that, I think I now just have a race condition.

What I'd really like is to have ffmpeg change the filename once it has completed a segment, and/or move the completed segment file into a different folder. However, this doesn't seem like an option. Is there a more robust way to accomplish what I'm doing here? I could just poll for multiple files with a given filename pattern, and process the earliest, circumventing the segments list file...but something more robust would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At loglevel 40 / verbose or higher, you can grep ffmpeg's log for the word `ended` and see lines like these:

```
[segment @ 000002d338781120] segment:'Mymon/Cam1_out20221228_093412.mp4' count:23 ended
```

Get the log by reading stderr or by adding -report to generate a logfile.